# On button click textbox inisde nested gridview concatinate old and new value

Tags: gridview, nested, duplicates

I have a nested gridview  that contain in child grid a textbox camp to set the price
[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0rUA.png)

If I insert the price the first time it's works fine but if I update the price it will concatenate the old value and the new one [Picture after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9agla.png)

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: what is the function that you are running within the onclick

Comment: i delete all rows relative to the compagnyId First then i insert directly

Comment: ok.. but, can you paste the code here?

Comment: [http://s31.postimg.org/sncnxdacb/prriiiiis.png]